# C# customcontrol cannnot update but OnPropertyChanged was triggered

Tags: c#, data-binding, wpf-controls

//here is my CustomControl's code behind

> I dont know why the Property Text is changed and the OnPropertyChange("Text")is successfully triggered,but in the mainwindows,which has a customcontrol call Mystatusbar,the text in this customcontrol cannot update and remain background black(I set it)

```
namespace ExternalControl
{

    public partial class MyStatusBar : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MyStatusBar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private string text = "状态栏";

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// 状态栏显示的Text的入口
        /// </summary>
        public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return text;
            }
            set
            {
                this.text = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Text");
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChangedEvent = PropertyChanged;
            if (propertyChangedEvent != null)
            {
                propertyChangedEvent(this, new 
                   PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        private void _StatusBar_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Text=DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        }

        private void UserControl_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Text=DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        }
    }
}




        //here is my mainwindow code behind
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {        
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`INotifyPropertyChanged` doesn't belong in your custom controls. It belongs in your (view)models.

For a custom control that has a property that you wish to bind to, use a [custom Dependency Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/cc903933(v=vs.95)).

Answer (score 0):

Kwinten is right.
On the other hand if you just want to make it work, try editing you user control constructor with this code:

```
public MyStatusBar()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```